# linux contextually process stderr only if present

Tags: linux, shell-script, stderr

I want to only have a process called if there actually *is* a STDERR present, but I don't know how to evaluate if one is actually present or not.  This code:

```bsh
errtest() {
  kubectl get namespace -A
  kubectl get namespace -A 2> >(echo "why am I here")
}
> errtest
```

Output:

```
NAME                               STATUS   AGE
2c74fd3b89e64077afd34d8ab8af4f09   Active   10d
845d1f1c71ed42c8b9e4c780992a95c0   Active   367d
why am I here
NAME                               STATUS   AGE
2c74fd3b89e64077afd34d8ab8af4f09   Active   10d
845d1f1c71ed42c8b9e4c780992a95c0   Active   367d
```

Obviously the first time shows that the output doesn't have any error, so the primary question is, why is "why am I here" showing?  That seems counterintuitive.

The secondary question is, in this case, how could I identify the STDERR so that I can work on context? Something like:

```
      kubectl get namespace -A 2> >(if [[ -z STDERR ]]; then echo "there is an error"; fi)
```

Comment: `ifne`. Can you take it from here?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100720/70524 stick `ifne` in the process substitution

Comment: it's also a bash builtin with `read -t 0 dummy`  (since bash is already used in the question)

Answer (score 0):

So the understanding needed to resolve this issue is what is being passed to

```
>(echo "why am I here")
```

.. specifically, a *resource* which can be read line by line.  AFAIK the resource is not something that can be (easily) passed further.  Or referenced as a variable.  This was the solution I had:

```
errtest() {
  random_variable="hello this works"
  # yes you can pass parameters as well..
  kubectl get namespace -A 2> >(errtest_if $random_variable)
}
errtest_if() {
  while read line; do
    echo "parameter 1 is $1"
    echo $line          #<< first line of the error
    #evaluate it if desired
    echo "looks like you are not logged in"
    #maybe call something else if desired

    #break if you only need to know there _is_ an error
    break
  done
}
> errtest
```

NOTE: as far as using `ifne` I chose not to because a) it wasn't installed on my linux and b) if that's true for me then it'll be true for someone else.

Comment: Small problem with `while read line`: if input doesn't end with a newline, any text after the last newline won't be processed by the loop.

Comment: In [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/700004/116858), you say you're using `zsh`. This is not available by default on all Linux systems. Would that not be the same issue as using `ifne` from the `moreutils` package? `ifne` is, after all, a utility made specifically for solving the issue that you have.